How to receive cell changed value in ASPxGridView with different cell types in a same column?
I have a VB.NET web project where I use DevExpress 20.1 version
I'm creating a grid which is empty in the first time and when a line is added grdVariablesFiltro_HtmlDataCellPrepared function is launched.
Depending of the type, the cell type od the columns VALOR and CONDICION are also changing.
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdVariablesFiltro" 
    ClientInstanceName="grdVariablesFiltro" Visible="true" 
    EnableCallBacks="true" SettingsResizing-ColumnResizeMode="Control" 
    KeyFieldName="ID_VARIABLE"  runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
    OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="grdVariablesFiltro_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
    <Settings HorizontalScrollBarMode="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarMode="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarStyle="Standard" 
              ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="true" 
              ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true"/>
    <SettingsPager PageSize="10">
        <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" ShowAllItem="true" />
    </SettingsPager>

    <SettingsBehavior AllowSort="true" AllowDragDrop="true" 
                      AllowSelectByRowClick="true" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="false" 
                      EnableCustomizationWindow="false" /> 

    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn HeaderStyle-BackColor="White" ShowSelectCheckbox="true" SelectAllCheckboxMode="AllPages" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="60"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID_VARIABLE" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colIdVariable" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SECCION" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colSeccion" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="APARTADO"  Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colApartado" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DESC_VARIABLE" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colDescVariable" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CLAVERO" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colClavero" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CONDICION" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colCondicion" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="VALOR" Width="10%" meta:resourcekey="colValor" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtValor" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("VALOR") %>'>
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

Protected Sub grdVariablesFiltro_HtmlDataCellPrepared(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs)
        If e.DataColumn.FieldName = "ID_VARIABLE" Then 'Obtenemos la variable al que le estamos asignando el tipo de celda
            If e IsNot Nothing Then
                If e.CellValue IsNot Nothing Then
                    variableAAnadir = e.CellValue.ToString()
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf e.DataColumn.FieldName = "VALOR" Or e.DataColumn.FieldName = "CONDICION" Then
            Dim tipoVariable As Integer = VariablesDAL.GetTipoUsuarioVariable(variableAAnadir)

            If e.DataColumn.FieldName = "VALOR" Then
                gestionarColumnaValor(e, tipoVariable)
            Else
                gestionarColumnaCondicion(e, tipoVariable) 'Segun el tipo de dato ponemos unas condiciones u otras
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    'Gestiona la columna de valor segun el tipo
    Protected Sub gestionarColumnaValor(e As ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs, tipoVariable As Integer)
        If tipoVariable = 3 Then 'TEXTO
            Dim textBox As New ASPxTextBox()
            textBox.Text = e.CellValue.ToString()
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(textBox)
        ElseIf tipoVariable = 1 Or tipoVariable = 2 Then 'NUMERO
            Dim spinEdit As New ASPxSpinEdit()
            'spinEdit.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(e.CellValue)

            spinEdit.ReadOnly = False

            e.Cell.Controls.Add(spinEdit)
        ElseIf tipoVariable = 101 Then 'SI NO
            Dim comboBox As New ASPxComboBox()
            comboBox.Items.Add("SI")
            comboBox.Items.Add("NO")
            'comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items.FindByText(e.CellValue.ToString())
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(comboBox)
        Else 'TIPOS DE USUARIO
            Dim listaValores As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
            'Leemos la lista de tipos 
            listaValores = VariablesDAL.GetValoresTipoUsuario(tipoVariable)

            If listaValores.Count > 0 Then
                Dim comboBox As New ASPxComboBox()

                'Recorremos la lista para rellenar el combo
                For Each valor In listaValores
                    comboBox.Items.Add(valor)
                Next

                e.Cell.Controls.Add(comboBox)
            End If

        End If
    End Sub

    'Gestiona la columna de condicion segun el tipo.
    Protected Sub gestionarColumnaCondicion(e As ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs, tipoVariable As Integer)
        Dim comboBox As New ASPxComboBox()
        If tipoVariable = 1 Or tipoVariable = 2 Then 'NUMERICO
            comboBox.Items.Add("=")
            comboBox.Items.Add("!=")
            comboBox.Items.Add("<")
            comboBox.Items.Add(">")
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(comboBox)
        Else
            comboBox.Items.Add("=")
            comboBox.Items.Add("!=")
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(comboBox)
        End If

        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 ' Esto selecciona el primer elemento que es "="
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(comboBox)
    End Sub

Then when the user changes the value of some of the editing columns, I want to receive the changed value. Can be at the moment or also when pressing a button.
How I can achieve this?
I have tried using onrowupdating and some other event launchers but I can't achieve to go to VB.
